# execute statement only if an exception occurs but when multiple catch clauses in place

Tags: php

I need to rollback transaction and send correct response to the client if anything in the try block fails so I do it like that:

```
try {
    $wf = $this->createWordForm($requestParams);
    $wfl = $this->createWordFormLink($requestParams, $wf);
    $wordList = $this->bindWordFormOrLinkToTextWord($requestParams, $wf, $wfl);
    $db->commit();
} catch (Kohana_ORM_Validation_Exception $e) {
    $exceptionHasOccured = TRUE;
    return JsonResponse::ValidationFail($this->response, $e->errors());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $exceptionHasOccured = TRUE;
    return JsonResponse::Error($this->response, $e->getMessage());
} finally {
    if ($exceptionHasOccured) {
        $db->rollback();
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using finally construction to rollback transaction. Is this correct approach?

Comment: I'd just duplicate the `$db->rollback()` line in both `catch` blocks. Keep it simple

Comment: @Phil thanks, that's what I did initially :)

Answer (score 1):

You could catch all exceptions in one catch block, as long as your not specifically using the exception type for any purpose.

```
try {
    $wf = $this->createWordForm($requestParams);
    $wfl = $this->createWordFormLink($requestParams, $wf);
    $wordList = $this->bindWordFormOrLinkToTextWord($requestParams, $wf, $wfl);
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $db->rollback();
    if($e instanceof Kohana_ORM_Validation_Exception ) { 
       return JsonResponse::ValidationFail($this->response, $e->errors());
    } else {
       return JsonResponse::Error($this->response, $e->getMessage())
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm returning different types of errors depending on the exception type

Comment: Added a fix for that. @Maximus

Comment: Good eyes. Updated again with a possible way of doing it, with still one rollback only.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that one too, thanks. I upvoted. However, I guess I'll still stick with the option of two rollback statements.